# Neither Windows 7 or Ubuntu will boot after installing 16.04. Any suggestions on how to fix my mistakes?

Tags: boot, 16.04, system-installation, windows-7

I previously had 12.x LTS installed, and decided to upgrade. After uninstalling it, I made myself a LiveUSB to install with.

My plan was to install Ubuntu onto a large external hard drive, and run it from there.

However, when I tried to install, I kept receiving an alignment error. I used fdisk to create some properly aligned partitions, and Ubuntu then let me go through with the install.

When I restarted my PC, instead of getting the expected OS selection screen, I get grub's rescue console.

I'll admit I'm out of my depth. Right now, I'm just wondering what I can do to get things booting correctly. Any ideas what I did I wrong, or how to set things right?

EDIT: My Windows install was under legacy BIOS, and I accidently installed Ubuntu under UEFI. My guess is that's where I went wrong. Still open to advice on how to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a system with a mix of UEFI and MSR installs. Big mess.

You can have either UEFI or MBR (aka UEFI Legacy), never both.

It is possible to convert the drive to either using Windows Repair CD's 'diskpart' command. Use diskpart in the console and type help, its documented good enough to get you through. Thats the princpile use:

```
diskpart 
> list disk
> select disk 0
> ICanNotRememberCommand MBR
```

It erases your disk, though. You need to copy all partitions and you will need to run Windows Repair through all stages to get it back. When it does not detect your Windows installation, install Linux onto another partition and put grub into the MBR. After that windows repair showed me the partition and the automatic install ran 3 cycles and I got windows back to run.

Its a very bad situation. To avoid to be ever in such a situation again I made the rule:

- all systems with system disk <2GB NEVER use UEFI, always use Uefi Legacy.
- all system with system disk >2GB only use UEFI.

Hope it helps,
CatMan

PS: When you try to take images with Clonezilla, it will not work when it finds a mismatch between MBR and GPT. I guess you will get this. In that case Clonezilla suugests the use of a 'sgdrive' command. I had nothing valuable to loose, so I tried it and it worked find, but it could have deleted the data on the drive as well. I did not try other backup tools.

Comment: Thanks for helping to clear thing up. After giving my manufacturer's repair disk a try, and forcing Ubuntu to install in legacy, I was finally able to get to the OS selection screen. I'll just have to chalk this up to a learning experience.

Comment: Glad it got you a bit further.